# A icon that is supposed to be in the header portion of my site is below it?

Tags: html, css

My page should have the twitter icon be on the same level as the logo and the blue background yet it is below it.

I have check the padding and any source of the issue!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <!-- set character encoding for the document -->
      <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta name="description" content="A description of the page">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="superfish.css">
      <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7a86a996d7.js"></script>
      <script
         src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
         integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="hoverIntent.js"></script>
      <script src="superfish.js"></script>
      <script>
         jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
         });

      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header">
         <p id="headerleft">
            <a href="http://www.wdwfantasy.com/" title="Disney Information"><img src="wdwfantasy.png" alt="Disney Information" height="100px" width="105px"></a>
         </p>
         <p id="headerright">
            <a href="http://www.twitter.com/wdwfantasy" target="_blank"><img src="twitter.png" alt="twitter" height="100px" width="105px" </a>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div id="nav">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS

```
div{ 
    display:block;

}

#header_container {
    background: #FFF url(https://images.wdwinfo.com/design/header-bg.jpg);
    height: 75px;
    zoom: 1;
}

#header{
    background: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 950px;
    height: 110px;
    background: #ebf1f6;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ebf1f6 0%, #abd3ee 50%, #89c3eb 51%, #d5ebfb 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ebf1f6 0%,#abd3ee 50%,#89c3eb 51%,#d5ebfb 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ebf1f6 0%,#abd3ee 50%,#89c3eb 51%,#d5ebfb 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ebf1f6', endColorstr='#d5ebfb',GradientType=0 );
}

#headerright{
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}

}

#headerleft {
    float:left;
    width:850px;
    background-color: grey;
    height:50px;
    width: 850px;
}
```

What could be the source of the issue?

Anything helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `}` after `#headerright` on your styles which is breaking the code. Removing it should make your float more inline with your logo.

**[---> Check external Fiddle <---](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/ozeuoLtp/10/)**

[image]

Comment: Thank You! Fixed the issue!